# apply function/formula cross rows

Tags: r

I have a table looks like

```
  stamp  a  b    expected result (euclidean distance)
    1    2  1    (3-2)**2+(1-1)**2
    2    3  1    (1-3)**2+(4-1)**2
    3    1  4    last one can be default defined
```

how can I get the expected result based on the computation of a rolling function from stamp 1 to the end across rows. Or do you have any other method?

I want to use it along with aggregate function so one single function to do this should be the solution.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your data like this

```
dd<-read.table(text="stamp  a  b
    1    2  1
    2    3  1
    3    1  4", header=T)
```

you could do something like

```
dd$dist<-c(with(dd, sqrt(diff(a)^2 + diff(b)^2)), NA)
```

to get the pairwise distances

```
  stamp a b     dist
1     1 2 1 1.000000
2     2 3 1 3.605551
3     3 1 4       NA
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, just curious, is there any more general solution to express the relationship cross rows in a function like , constructing a formula f(a[i],a[i+1])+g(b[i],b[i+1])

Comment: I know of none that I would recommend for all cases. It all depends on the function and the results you need.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
dat$dist <- c(diag(as.matrix(dist(dat[2:3]))[-1, -nrow(dat)]), NA)

#   stamp a b     dist
# 1     1 2 1 1.000000
# 2     2 3 1 3.605551
# 3     3 1 4       NA
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.